# Cross-browser text chat application with node and WebRTC

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, socket.io, chat, webrtc

I'm new to JavaScript and node and specially WebRTC, I tried some tutorials and I'm getting little bit better.

My goal is to make a chat application (it should be cross-browser) using WebRTC protocol.
This application should be with node.
It is very possible and I saw someone talking about it in a forum.

I encountered many problems, for example, I couldn't send text using WebRTC, also I'm not used to use socket.io with node, and to worst that I do not know too much networking.

Comment: Socket.io deals with WebSockets, not WebRTC.

Comment: Also, WebRTC isn't really a protocol, it's more of a concept and a group of APIs.

Comment: If you use node and socket.io the official tutorial at http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ contains a copy pasteable guide to creating a simple chat. If you encounter any problems with it, try asking a more specific question, your current question is to broad.

Comment: @Jamen Actually the latest Socket.io *can* use webrtc for p2p direct messaging: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/

Comment: @xdumaine, Oh, I wasn't under the impression that existed...  Seems like it was just announced July 14th too.